# What happens during hoisting?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was going through the hoisting concept of javascript.

```
    var a = 2;
    function a(){};
    typeof a 
    // "number"

    var a ;
    function a(){};
    typeof a 
    // "function"
```

My question is, why first code has typeof number instead of funtion which can be seen in second part of the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you break the first code it looks like this. In js, function declarations hoist the function definitions.

To show the function declarations hoist the function definitions you can call function `a()` before declaration

```js
var a; // a is undefined
a();

function a() {
  console.log('function a');
}; // function is also hoisted
a = 2; // a is assigned a value
console.log(typeof a)
```

Comment: Does that mean first variables are hoisted and then functions?

Answer (score 2):

**function declarations hoists first than normal variable initialization.**
The variables declared with `var` shows hoisting. The declaration of `a` goes to top of scope but its assigned the value `2` on the line where its written.

The function declaration i.e `function a(){};` declared the value and also assigns the value to function at top of scope. So whats happening in first example is

```js
var a = function(){};
a = 2;
console.log(typeof a)
```

In the second example the variable is initialized to a function. But `var a` doesnot change `a` from function to `undefined`

```js
var a = function(){};
a; //this doesnot change a
console.log(typeof a);
```

Comment: Which is hoisted the first variables of functions?

Comment: @ShivamMuttoo function declaration is always hoisted first.